# Will buying another ceo remove the office garage?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I currently own a CEO office with an office garage. I was thinking of trading the office for a different one. Will the office garage get transferred into the new one or will i have to buy another? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

i also tested this..... buying a different CEO office will indeed transfer your office garages with all cars

i had the maze tower office and had to spend 3mil to switch offices and back, so i really hope this helps someone in need

Answer (score 0):

I tested trading in CEO offices to see if the garages would transfer and the garages did transfer to the new CEO office that I bought. I hope this helps you.